# In Java Swing how to capture radio group selection within a table cell editor?

Tags: java, swing

I added a radio button group to a JTable column and defined TableCellRenderer and TableCellEditor. The JTable is populated dynamically. When I click on the column, I see that TableCellRenderer and TableCellEditor are called. However, if I change the selection within that radio button group, I have no way of knowing what the user selected.

Could someone possibly help?

Thanks

Comment: You could add an ActionListener to each of the JRadioButtons as you add them to the table.

Comment: The value should be getting past to your `TableModel` via the `setValueAt` method. The `JTable` will be asking the editor for it's value when editing stops and passing it to your table